# как поменять название файла для мобильной версии

Tags: javascript, php, веб-программирование

Нужно прописать условие для вывода изображений под разные устройства

<img src="if (screen.width < 480){ {$slide.image_url}.replace(".jpg", "_mobil.jpg");}else{{$slide.image_url}}">

{$slide.image_url} - базовое изображение.

Суть - что бы на экранах меньше 480px подставлялись другие рисунки. Они уже предварительно подготовлены и имеют имена *_mobil.jpg

Например:
1.jpg  а на мобильном будет показывать 1_mobil.jpg

Comment: Почитайте [Адаптивные изображения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images)

Comment: другие изображения нужно выводить с помощью HTML тега [picture](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) или через CSS свойство `display` с `@media` запросами

Answer (score 0):

Используйте picture

```
<picture>
 <source srcset="{$slide.image_url|replace:'.jpg':'_mobil.jpg')}" media="(max-width: 480px)">
 <img src="{$slide.image_url}">
</picture>
```

Comment: Условие срабатывает. Но наименования неправильно выдает. Показывает 404 
 .....6%D0%B042.jpg_mobil.jpg.jpg  Нужно  .....6%D0%B042_mobil.jpg

Comment: Забыл добавить .replace. Исправил. Проверьте.

Comment: Ещё раз исправил))

Comment: Также 404      .......5%D1%807.jpg.replace('.jpg' Именно в переименновании глюк.

Comment: также пробовал $slide.image_url|replace:'.jpg','_mobil.jpg' ...так как там шаблон .tpl  и используется smarty (CMS Prestashop)

Comment: в синтаксисе смарти не силен, немного погуглив сделал изменения проверьте

Comment: Все равно спасибо тебе за поддержку и частичное решение

Comment: Получается мой код в ответе все таки сработал, зачем ты его скопировал в свой ответ?)

Comment: после того как я скинул предположение, что я пробовал (была ошибка в запятой ) ты сказал то в смарти не очень и скинул вариант также с ошибкой ( сейчас вник - оказывается скобка одна не нужна и код не работал ). Я продолжил разбираться дальше со своим синтаксисом.  Еще раз благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Сработаал следующий код

```html
<picture>
<source srcset="{$slide.image_url|replace:'.jpg':'_mobil.jpg'}" media="(max-width: 480px)">
 <img src="{$slide.image_url}">
</picture>
```